# Trying to understand output of model.get_weights() in keras

Tags: machine-learning

To get a feeling of how neural nets work, I decided to train a super simple 2-1 net to add up its two inputs. Here's my code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math

x_train = np.random.rand(10000,2)
y_train = x_train[:,0]+x_train[:,1]

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
              metrics = [])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)

for i in model.get_weights():
    print(i,'\n')
```

The last `for` loop outputs the following.

```
[[ 0.8512728   1.555682  ]
 [-0.04689309  1.6778996 ]] 

[-0.23842156 -0.06958904] 

[[0.09876956]
 [0.583725  ]] 

[0.08260487]
```

The model behaves well, with an average mean square error of around 0.0001. However...

- I don't understand why there are **two** weight matrices. Why isn't there only one, namely the weights from the first (input) to the second (output) layer?
- How could I go about performing the same calculations as my model `model` given those weights and biases? Like, I think I knew the basic algebraic theory of neural nets but now that this first 2x2 weight matrix shows up, I'm not really sure of how it works. In particular, given an input ***x***, and considering the weights and biases from the aforequoted output as *W0, b0, W1, b1* respectively, I've tried to compute ***y**=W1(W0x+b0)+b1* but this really isn't near the output of the net, i.e. ***y*** strongly disagrees with *(1,1)**x***.

Please, can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: This question may be a better fit on some other sites on the SE network.